# Pandas dataframe selecting date specific information and re-assigning column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select

Pandas df 'inndata' with weekly interval data:

| Date | Item | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-21-2021 | aa | -100 | 50 | -50 |
|  | bb | 100 | 100 | 200 |
|  | cc | 300 | -50 | 250 |
| 12-28-2021 | aa | 75 | -50 | 25 |
|  | bb | -75 | -50 | -125 |
|  | cc | 50 | 100 | 150 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 12-20-2022 | aa | 200 | 55 | 255 |
|  | bb | -25 | -50 | -75 |
|  | cc | -100 | 100 | 0 |

Using pandas, how do I select rows at chosen intervals, for example 1 week and/or 1 year, while leaving out others, and report the data from column Z, for a result resembling the following table with historical data going back in time?

| Item | 1W | 1YR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | -50 | 255 |
| bb | 200 | -75 |
| cc | 250 | 0 |

Unsuccessful attempt:

```
inndata['Z'] = pd.DataFrame({
              '1W': df.iloc[0,:]
             ,'1YR': df.iloc[-52,:]
            }).T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest using the own pandas tools. Assuming that `inndata` have a Pandas `MultiIndex` with ***Date*** and ***Item***.

First, create a `filter` array, having `most_recent_date` obtained from ***Date*** values:

```
>>> columns = ['1W', '1YR']
>>> weeks = [1, 52]
>>> filter = [most_recent_date - pd.Timedelta(weeks=w) for w in weeks]
```

Then we can apply the `filter` to the level of ***Date*** and get the values.

```
>>> idx_level = inndata.index.get_level_values('Date')
>>> df = inndata.loc[idx_level.isin(filter)]
```

Now, sort the `MultiIndex` of `df` with ***Date*** descending,

```
>>> df.sort_index(level=['Date', 'Item'], ascending=[False, True], inplace=True)
```

replace it with columns names that we want, using a `dict`

```
>>> d = dict(zip(filter, columns))
>>> idx = df.index.levels[0].to_series().replace(d)
>>> df.index = df.index.set_levels(idx, level='Date')
```

and unstack the level ***Date***. This convert it to columns

```
>>> df = df.unstack(level='Date')
>>> df.columns.rename(None, inplace=True)
```

Finally, we get the `DataFrame` with the resumed information.

| Item | 1W | 1YR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | -50 | 255 |
| bb | 200 | -75 |
| cc | 250 | 0 |

Comment: This helped a lot with index variable 'most_recent_date'